# COLLADA files and geographic coordinates

Tags: kml, coordinates, multipatch, collada

I am failing to understand something here, from the arcgis help page:

> "The Multipatch To COLLADA tool can be used to export multipatches to
>   COLLADA files on disk. COLLADA is a 3D model format that is supported
>   in many 3D applications, including Google Earth. If the multipatch
>   feature class you are converting is in a projected coordinate system,
>   **the tool will create a KML file in the output folder which will assign geographic coordinates to the 3D models in the COLLADA files"**

When I convert a multipatch to COLLADA i see nothing more than the .DAE files. Anyone encounter this before?